# Get Frames from Video in c#

Tags: c#, video

I am working on uploading a video using file upload control in MVC view and I am uploading a video from this file upload control.On the server side I want to get the frames/Images of video.I have to get the frame in byte but I can do it for the a single file but I am not sure about video file.
I have googled a lot but did not get any perfect solution even I tried with the Framegrabber but it is also not working.

Can anyone help me how can i get frames from video.

Thanks

Comment: Please tell me the reason to mark negative to this question?If you have any idea where i am wrong .please make me correct

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) on the server side to create thumbnails from the video using FFMPEG, commands [here](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video).

The command line looks like:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -f image2 -vf "select='eq(pict_type,PICT_TYPE_I)'" -vsync vfr thumb%04d.png
```

Comment: I want to integrate this in the website not in the desktop application.is this work in the web application

Comment: As long as you can install ffmpeg on your web server and run your web application with the right permissions, you ought to be able to do this, yes.